# Module build failed: @import "style"; ^ Invalid CSS after "e": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was 'export default "@im'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, sass-loader

I am working on a rails app with vue in the front end. I am getting this error below when I try to run the webpack server. I read about this issue on stack overflow and some suggested to add raw-loader but it didn't fix the issue for me. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
Module build failed: 
@import "style";
^
      Invalid CSS after "e": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was 'export default "@im'
      in /Users/weather/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const vue =  require('./loaders/vue')
environment.loaders.append('vue', vue)
environment.loaders.append('jshint', {
  test: /\.js$/,
  enforce: "pre",
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
      loader: "jshint-loader"
  }]
});

environment.loaders.append('sass', {
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader'
    }
  ]
});

environment.loaders.append('raw', {
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'raw-loader',
    }
  ]
});

const resolver = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  }
};
environment.config.merge(resolver);

module.exports = environment;
```

application.scss

```
@import "style";
@import "top_menu";
```

style.sass

```
.dropdown-items
    font-weight: bold
    position: absolute
    background-color: red
    min-width: 130px
    z-index: 1

    a
      display: block
      color: white

      &:hover, &:focus
        text-decoration: none
```

top_menu.sass

```
.menu-top
    top: 2.9rem !important
    right: 7.3rem !important

    .menu-out
      right: 3em
      top: 1.5em
```

Comment: webpack loaders process from bottom to top, try to rearrange the loaders.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have it in the question. application.scss

Comment: @PatricNox can you suggest me how I should arrange them?

Comment: @JaromandaX no worries.